# Is Forticlient VPN available for Raspbian OS?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-jessie, vpn

I have a `Fortinet VPN` server, to which I connect through [FortiClient](https://forticlient.com/downloads)  from my Windows 10 PC. Can I install FortiClient for Raspberry Pi `Raspbian OS` (when I do `sudo apt install forticlient` it does not locate the package)?
If not are there any other options to connect to `Fortinet VPN` on Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 3):

I use openfortivpn too.

install with:
apt install openfortivpn

start with:
sudo openfortivpn *[forticlienthost]* --username=*[user]*

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have two questions:

Q1: Installing FortiClient for Raspberry Pi:

A1: Fortinet is not open-source software. Consequently, it would be very unlikely that there would be a client for Raspberry Pi. I see from their website they do offer a Linux version, but it wouldn't run on Raspbian because RPi uses an ARM processor. So, the answer to this question is, "No, you cannot install `forticlient`." FYI, you should [read the APT documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/apt.md) as it may help you avoid asking questions here that you can easily answer yourself.

Q2: Other options to connect to Fortinet VPN on Raspberry Pi?

[Fortinet's website has a couple of "cookbooks"](https://www.fortinet.com/products/vpn.html) that deal with making connections via IPsec and SSL. You might wish to view these (I didn't) to see if they offer any useful suggestions. In other words, you ***might*** be able to hack a solution on the RPi to get it to connect.

But my advice would be to get a good open-source firewall/VPN package (e.g. [OPNsense](https://opnsense.org/)) instead of tackling what's likely a challenging effort connecting RPi to a commercial, closed source VPN server. That's just my  opinion though - you should try it if it interests you. If you do decide to try an open-source solution for your server, you can Google `openvpn client raspberry pi 3` to get some help in setting up a VPN on the RPi.

Answer (score 1):

So far the only solution I have found to work is to use the web browser SSL VPN setup on the Fortigate, and then connect using the Raspian (Buster) Chromium browser. You wont have tunnel mode but for RDP, SSH etc it works fine.

For apps that require tunnel mode my workaround is to create a RDP/VNC desktop/jumpbox with supporting software on the network which has access to the app, so basically I use the Fortigate web VPN client to RDP/VNC to a remote desktop that can run the app I require.

I tried various options to get a native tunnel client working to no avail because nothing is compiled for ARM. The closest to getting something working I found is compiling openfortigui - however, there were some compile errors when I tried, so looks like the source code requires modification to support Raspberry/ARM in some way.

I have heard that it may be possible to configure something like Strongswan (available to install on Raspian) to connect to a Fortigate VPN using IPSec, but I have not seen this working or done it, so take it with a grain of salt until you know different.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed this using 
https://salsa.debian.org/debian/openfortivpn
Use the armhf package from:
https://packages.debian.org/buster/openfortivpn
Which works a charm.

Comment: do this works if there is two factor authentication?